# Forcing subfigures to have same height and take overall X% of linewidth in LaTeX

Tags: floats

I want to make a figure composed of two images that have different sizes. I want to put them side by side so that they have the same height and that they overall take, say, 90% of the line width.

It is easy to make them have the same fixed height (say in cm), but how to let this common height be automatically adjusted to fulfill the desired overall width? Manual trial-and-error is time-consuming, approximate and non robust.

A solution with or without `subfigure` or another LaTeX package is OK.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can include them to the same (more or less arbitrary) height then scale them together to the desired width

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}% images from mwe package

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{center}
\resizebox{.9\textwidth}{!}{%
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
\quad
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-16x9}%
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: He said "It is easy to make them have the same fixed height (say in cm), but how to let this common height be automatically adjusted to fulfill the desired overall width? Manual trial-and-error is time-consuming, approximate and non robust."

Comment: @Astrinus that's what he said, and that's what this does

Comment: You are fixing an height, but what if both the images are taller than wider?

Comment: @Astrinus Those images _are_ different sizes/aspect ratios, that's why I chose them. The `3cm` height is arbitrary it just affects the space between them. It is changed by the `!` passed to resizebox to meet the specified total width. try changing it to 5cm to see what I mean.

Comment: Oh. I didn't even notice that exclamation mark!

Comment: Thx! Is there any easy way to adapt this to have a fixed (in cm or `\textwidth`) inter-image spacing (so that height choice really becomes arbitrary)?

Comment: @user1735003 not really, you'd have to measure and scale "by hand" so the markup would be quite a bit more complicated. Possible of course.

Comment: I created a small package which allows you to create rows of figures: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227935/different-aspect-ratio-images-full-width-same-height-row-layout

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would it be possible to add subcaptions to the images? Thank you.

Comment: @codeaviator it's better to ask a question as a new question rather than comments but not so easy to add sub captions here as you don't want to scale the caption text, unless you know that (say) making tow equal width captiosn evenly spaced out would be OK, in which case just have two minipage with teh captions in a paragraph below this scaled image box

Comment: @Herbert does your minipackage solely exist on tex.se? Why is it not on ctan?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `subcaption` package and do the computation as suggested by David.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}% images from mwe package
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength{\twosubht}
\newsavebox{\twosubbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill The text width\hrulefill

\begin{center}
\makebox[.9\textwidth]{\hrulefill 90\% of text width\hrulefill}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[htp]

% preliminary
\sbox\twosubbox{%
  \resizebox{\dimexpr.9\textwidth-1em}{!}{%
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-16x9}%
  }%
}
\setlength{\twosubht}{\ht\twosubbox}

% typeset

\centering

\subcaptionbox{First\label{f}}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\twosubht]{example-image-a}%
}\quad
\subcaptionbox{Second\label{s}}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\twosubht]{example-image-16x9}%
}

\caption{The caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, (so +1 and thanks!) but what is going on here? Is the "preliminary" part solely for estimating the height and then never used other than that?

Comment: @lucidbrot In the preliminary part, the two images are set together, in order to compute the final height, but then we need to insert them separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength{\totalimgwidth}
\newlength{\imgspacingwidth}

\newlength{\firstimgorigwidth}
\newlength{\firstimgorigheight}
\newlength{\secondimgorigwidth}
\newlength{\secondimgorigheight}
\newlength{\firstimgwidth}
\newlength{\secondimgwidth}

\newcommand{\setsubfloatwidths}[2]{%set the total width you want the images take and the spacing between them
\setlength{\totalimgwidth}{#1}%
\setlength{\imgspacingwidth}{#2}%
\addtolength{\totalimgwidth}{-\imgspacingwidth}%
}


\begin{document}
\setsubfloatwidths{0.9\textwidth}{1ex} %set the total width of figure and spacing inbetween
\begin{figure}
\adjincludegraphics[gstore width=\firstimgorigwidth,gstore height=\firstimgorigheight,gobble]{img1}%
\adjincludegraphics[gstore width=\secondimgorigwidth,gstore height=\secondimgorigheight,gobble]{img2}%
\makeatletter%
\FPdiv\firstaspectratio{\strip@pt\firstimgorigheight}{\strip@pt\firstimgorigwidth}%
\FPdiv\secondaspectratio{\strip@pt\secondimgorigheight}{\strip@pt\secondimgorigwidth}%
\FPeval\firstfactor{\secondaspectratio / (\firstaspectratio + \secondaspectratio)}%
\FPeval\secondfactor{\firstaspectratio / (\firstaspectratio + \secondaspectratio)}%
\makeatother%
\begin{subfigure}{\firstfactor\totalimgwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img1}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\imgspacingwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\secondfactor\totalimgwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You set the total width you want the images take and the spacing between them with `\setsubfloatswidths`, then you call `\adjincludegraphics` inside the `figure` environment with the two image files as arguments, and finally you use subfigures as usual.

`\firstfactor` contains the factor which scales the first image and `\secondfactor` does the same for the second one.

A simpler solution could have been to set the height of the image, but `\subcaption`'s `subfigure` environment take as argument *the width* of the subfloat.

Comment: the graphics package can already scale while preserving aspect ratio so there's no need to do those divisions explicitly.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that if you want to use `subcaption` package, you have to pass it the widths of the subfloats.

Comment: packages are supposed to make things easier, not harder:-)