# How to have captions above each "pseudo-subfigure"?

Tags: graphics, captions, subcaption

The following subfigures are not real subfigures, but I will call them pseudo-subfigures, since I would like to have captions above them like one can easily do with real subfigures.

However, I would not like to use real subfigures (decided after having many compatibility issues, which I can not all remember).

Here might be some of the reasons why one would prefer to use pseudo-subfigures (I might be wrong, as my memory fails):

- It seems that it is a big chore (cf. [Forcing subfigures to have same height and take overall X% of linewidth in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218378/forcing-subfigures-to-have-same-height-and-take-overall-x-of-linewidth-in-latex)) to have real subfigures of equal height, while there is no labour with the pseudo-subfigures & (if wanted together with the previous) it seems to be even a bit more difficult to have sugfigures placed closely against each-other (cf. [Reduction of Space between two Sub-figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42968/reduction-of-space-between-two-sub-figures)).
- I think using real subfigures would also conflict with having the footnotes there...
- Somehow some other compatibility issue would appear, with some of the featured list items in relation to having the custom *figurer environment* (cf. code). In any way, I will use the *figurer environment* for each figure in my document of purpose, and thus will also use its numberings. Therefor, in casu, I would not like to revert to using real main figure captions.

### MWE

**P.S.: You need to compile this with LuaLaTex...**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% images from mwe package

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcounter{picture}

%%%%% figurer environment

\newmdenv[
hidealllines=true,
innertopmargin=16pt,
innerbottommargin=10pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
skipabove=10pt,
skipbelow=10pt,
singleextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ );
  \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) {[sharp corners] --
    ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
    ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O) --
    (O) -- cycle;
  \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
    {\refstepcounter{picture}\large Figure~\thepicture} ; 
  },
firstextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
  \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) {[sharp corners] --
    ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
    ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O) --
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O);
  \node[overlay] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
    {\refstepcounter{picture}\large Figure~\thepicture} ; 
  },
middleextra={
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (O);
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (P) -- 
    (P|-O);
  },
secondextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (O) --
    (P|-O) --
    (P);
  },
]{figurer}

%%%%% begin the beguine

\begin{document}

\begin{figurer}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image} 
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}

This would be my caption here (We can even have footnotes here).\footnote{I like how the footnote stays inside the figure box.}

\end{center}

\end{figurer}

\end{document}
```

Is it somehow possible to have pseudo-subcaptions above each pseudo-subfigure? They don't need to be numbered anything: thus no need for **a)**, **b)**, **c)** etc...

Let's imagine the pictures are from a person, and one would simply briefly like to indicate the age of the person above each image?

P.S.: I would like to have a dynamic solution, which would work with any number of pictures (at least any number of pictures on 1 line), while all pictures (at least on 1 line) can be of equal (but differing per MWE) height.

[image: MWE example]

**Please note that the text** "This would be my caption here" **is considered a "pseudo-caption" of the main "pseudo-figure" here, not a caption of any seperate "pseudo-subfigure".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest setting all the pseudo-subfigures inside a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ *{5}{c} }
    \small A & \small B & \small C & \small D & \small E \\
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}

This is a pseudo-caption.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

`tabular` columns expand relative to the widest element (caption or image). You can also adjust the inter-column spacing (given by `\tabcolsep`).