# How to automatically scale subfigures to have same height?

Tags: subfloats, scaling

I have a lot of figures to put side by side in a document, and they are all slightly different in size (i.e. not all 4:3 format or so).

What I'm doing at the moment is tweak the `width=0.XX\textwidth` of both until they look more or less the same height.

Here I provide an example code: what I would like to be able to do is have a macro or something, where I can simply provide the two figures and they automatically scale to have the same height and fit on one line. Is that possible? And if yes, how?

**Edit**: since people are asking why I'm not providing specific sizes for the images: The code should work with *any* 2 images with any aspect ratio. Give it two images and the code scales them to fit side by side **and** have the same height, filling the horizontal space available.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Figures}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Figure one]{%
            \centering\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[Figure two with different side proportions]{%
            \centering\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}}
        \caption{How to get the two figures to same height (respecting proportions)?}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What I get:

[image: what I get]

What I wish to happen automatically:

[image: what I wish to get]

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218414/36296 In contrast to just setting the height, this will still ensure that your images will still span the whole textwidth

Answer (score 3):

with defining (only) their height. like `\includegraphics[height=33mm]{example-image-a}}` (select the image height according to your wish).

off-topic: don't use `\centering` inside of subfloats ...

**edit:**

In your case, since you like to have in both images the same `height` to use key `Gin` as follows in edited code below. To push images apart as much as possible, use `\hfill` instead of `quad`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Figures}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \setkeys{Gin}{height=44mm}
        \subfloat[Figure one]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
        \hfill% push sub images apart, so take all the line
        \subfloat[Figure two with different side proportions]{%
            \includegraphics{example-image-16x9}}
        \caption{How to get the two figures to same height (respecting proportions)?}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: why not to use `\centering` inside a float?

Comment: @samcarter, because it hasn't any influence on positioning of image. `\subfloat` take a size of included image (as far as I know, but i can be wrong).

Comment: Why 33mm? How can I get them to fill most of the width as possible?

Comment: @Superuser27 - How is one supposed to determine how to "fill as much of the width as possible" if one doesn't have any information about (a) the height and width of the text block and (b) the aspect ratios of the images?

Comment: apparently i din't understand the question correctly, what you like to have... so i left to select desired height to you ...

Comment: "they are all slightly different in size". The code should scale them automatically independently of their actual sizes or aspect ratios. I don't know how to formulate that @Mico, sorry if that was unclear

Comment: @Zarko Ah, you mean subfloats! Then it makes sense. I tried to clarify the wording, please feel free to rollback my edit if you don't like it

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much for correcting my answer. now it is readable and without spurious bracket ...

Answer (score 3):

For the two sample graphs and the default text width and height given by the `scrreprt` document class, it suffices to replace `width=...` with `height=0.21\textheight`, for both `subfig` groups.

[image]

For other combinations of text widths, text heights, and proportions of the pairs of images that need to be placed next to each other, you'll probably have to experiment a bit to find out which value of `height=...` is about right.

I'm assuming that the objective is to make the pairs of graphs be as large as possible, i.e., span the full width of the textblock. If this assumption is valid, none of the `\centering` instructions are needed.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Figures}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\subfloat[Figure one]{%
\includegraphics[height=0.21\textheight]{example-image-a}}
\hspace*{\fill}
\subfloat[Figure two with different side proportions]{%
\includegraphics[height=0.21\textheight]{example-image-16x9}}
\caption{How to get the two figures to same height (respecting proportions)?}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The question was how I can get them to the same height **and** fill the page width **without** having to _experiment a bit_ :)

Comment: @Superuser27 - If you rule out experimenting of the type described above, you'll have to "play it safe" by providing more horizontal whitespace than is absolutely necessary. Put differently, what you'll be showing  your readers is *deliberately less detailed* than would be possible with just a bit of experimenting. In my experience, readers always appreciate being shown graphs that are as large as sensibly possible. Why disappoint them by showing them more whitespace instead? Naturally, you're free to do as you please -- and your readers are free to make up their own opinions...

Comment: Ok I try to rephrase the question: I would like to get the pictures to fill the page width, yet stay side by side (so the sum of their width should be around `0.9\textwidth` **and** they should have the same height. Automatically. :)

Comment: @Superuser27 - You've also failed to provide any exact information about the aspect ratios of the images, the width of the text block, and height of the text block. If such information were provided, one *could* in fact come up with a near-optimal calculation of the `height=...` option for various combinations of graphs. However, you chose not to provide these pieces of information.

Comment: I didn't provide any specific aspect ratios since that would remove the "automatically" part, wouldn't it. I don't want a code that works for two specific figures but a general one possibly. As I said in the question: "they are all slightly different in size".

Comment: @Superuser27: You might be interested in [Forcing subfigures to have same height and take overall X% of linewidth in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218378/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Thank you!! That's **exactly** what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

To get both images to the same height you can store the height of the first image in a dimension `\imageheight`. Then you can use `height=\imageheight` for the second image.

The culprit here is that you can not automaticly define the width of both images to fit the textwidth as good as possible. Perhaps an code with lua can do that but until now I did not learn to use lua in TeX ...

So let us do it semi automatic ...

Lets have a look into the code. With the line in the preamble

```
\newdimen\imageheight
```

we declare a new dimension `\imageheight` to store the height of the first image.
With the code

```
\settoheight{\imageheight}{% <==========================================
  \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
}
```

you get the current height of the image for a choosen width of `width=0.40\textwidth`.

Now you can use the code

```
\subfloat[Figure one]{%
  \centering\includegraphics[height=\imageheight]{example-image-a}}
\qquad
\subfloat[Figure two with different side proportions]{%
  \centering\includegraphics[height=\imageheight]{example-image-16x9}}
```

to print the images with same heigth. To get them fitting the textwifth just play with the width for the first image: `width=0.40\textwidth`. Change the value of `0.40\textwidth` to your needs.

The complete code

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newdimen\imageheight % to store the actual image height <==============


\begin{document}

\settoheight{\imageheight}{% <==========================================
  \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
}

\chapter{Figures}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \subfloat[Figure one]{%
      \centering\includegraphics[height=\imageheight]{example-image-a}} % <=============
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Figure two with different side proportions]{%
      \centering\includegraphics[height=\imageheight]{example-image-16x9}} % <==========
  \caption{How to get the two figures to same height (respecting proportions)?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives you the result:

[image]

Comment: Where does the `0.40\textwidth` come from? Do you have to guess that value depending on your image dimensions?

Comment: @TimKuipers Yes you have to guess and test it ...