# Multiple figures side by side with rasters tcoloborx

Tags: tcolorbox

**Context**

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218414/163874), I can have 2 figures side by side with **adjusted width, same height for sub-figures**.

[image]

The same approach works for multiple graphs to get something like

[image]

I created `\newcommand`  to include 2, 3, 4 graphs side by side. However, I could certainly benefit from automation of this task with keys.

**My question**

How can I adjust the `\width` of each `raster` (same height) so they can fit harmoniously on the `\textwidth` ?

How can I use `tcolorbox raster` for this task ?

[image]

So far, here is where I stand

[image]

turning to

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[
    showframe, 
    top = 1.8cm, 
    bottom = 2cm, 
    outer = 7cm, 
    inner = 2cm, 
    heightrounded, 
    marginparwidth = 5.0cm, 
    marginparsep = 0.5cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,patterns} % preamble
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\def\fullPage{\dimexpr \marginparwidth+\marginparsep+\textwidth\relax}

\newcommand{\myGraphiX}[2][2]{
\begin{tcbraster}[
%       raster width = \fullPage,
%       raster width = \textwidth,
        raster columns = #1,
%       raster force size = false,
%       raster equal height=rows,
        size = fbox,
        colframe = blue!50,
        colback = white,
        fonttitle = \bfseries,
        center title,
        drop fuzzy shadow,
    ]
        
\captionsetup{labelfont = {color = blue,bf,sf}}
                                
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 1st image]{example-image-golden}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 2nd image]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 3rd prime]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 4th matu]{example-image-duck}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 5th matu]{example-image-a}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 6th matu]{example-image-b}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 7th matu]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 8th matu]{example-image-c}

    \begin{tcbitemize}[
        raster multicolumn = #1, %Does not seem to work
        halign = left,
        colframe = white,
        colback = white,
    ]
    \tcbitem \captionof{table}{#2}
    \end{tcbitemize}
                                                    
\end{tcbraster}

}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Auto adjustment to figure height}

\myGraphiX[4]{\lipsum[1][1]}

\myGraphiX[8]{\lipsum[1][2]}

\myGraphiX[2]{\lipsum[1][3]}

\end{document}
```

**Next steps**

In a future question, I'll ask how to enter a list of figures with their captions to avoid hardcoding. But one step at a time :)

**Edit 1**

Using `raster equal height` as described in the anwer leads to

[image]

that is **not** what I am trying to reach.

Comment: try `raster equal height`

Comment: @DG' thank you but. using 
```\begin{tcbraster}[
%raster width = \fullPage,
%raster width = \textwidth,
raster columns = #1,
%raster force size = false,
%raster equal height=rows,
raster equal height,
size = fbox,
colframe = blue!50,
colback = white,
fonttitle = \bfseries,
center title,
drop fuzzy shadow,
]``` 
leads to the output in Edit 1

Comment: `tcbraster` divides `linewidth` in several equal width columns. If you want/need different width columns, you have to adjust them by hand.

Comment: @Ignasi Thank you for your extremely useful comment. As we say in French "it puts the church in the middle of the village" :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `raster equal height` I get this output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[
    showframe, 
    top = 1.8cm, 
    bottom = 2cm, 
    outer = 7cm, 
    inner = 2cm, 
    heightrounded, 
    marginparwidth = 5.0cm, 
    marginparsep = 0.5cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,patterns} % preamble
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\def\fullPage{\dimexpr \marginparwidth+\marginparsep+\textwidth\relax}

\newcommand{\myGraphiX}[2][2]{
\begin{tcbraster}[
%       raster width = \fullPage,
%       raster width = \textwidth,
        raster columns = #1,
%       raster force size = false,
%       raster equal height=rows,
        size = fbox,
        colframe = blue!50,
        colback = white,
        fonttitle = \bfseries,
        center title,
        drop fuzzy shadow,
        raster equal height, % <-- HERE
    ]
        
\captionsetup{labelfont = {color = blue,bf,sf}}
                                
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 1st image]{example-image-golden}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 2nd image]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 3rd prime]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 4th matu]{example-image-duck}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 5th matu]{example-image-a}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 6th matu]{example-image-b}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 7th matu]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \tcbincludegraphics[title = 8th matu]{example-image-c}

    \begin{tcbitemize}[
        raster multicolumn = #1, %Does not seem to work
        halign = left,
        colframe = white,
        colback = white,
    ]
    \tcbitem \captionof{table}{#2}
    \end{tcbitemize}
                                                    
\end{tcbraster}

}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Auto adjustment to figure height}

\myGraphiX[4]{\lipsum[1][1]}

\myGraphiX[8]{\lipsum[1][2]}

\myGraphiX[2]{\lipsum[1][3]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. The raster is fixed and the boxes are the same height. What do you want to change?

Comment: Same height yes, but the width is adjusted as you can see on the 3 graphs below "The same approach works for multiple graphs to get something like" in my question. I'd like to know if I can mimic that with rasters.

Comment: So you don't want a raster or grid after all?

Comment: I do actually. I updated the second image on my question to reflect that.

Comment: As far as I can see, you have to stick to columns. Maybe someone else finds a solution that allows flexible widths

Comment: Thank you for your investigation :)